# SQL Return multiple rows based on results of other row

Tags: sql

I'm trying to see what other SKUs have been purchased if SKU A was purchased.

What I have so far is something like:

```
Select *
    From Test 
    Where Transaction ID = Sku 'A'
```

but of course the where statement doesn't work. I don't have the ability to create new tables or anything but I think it should be possible to just do a query? Any help would be appreciated as I'm pulling my hair out here!

Thanks!

Table Name: Test ([Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4Hfo.png)):

```
+ -------------- + --- + ----------------- +
| Transaction ID | SKU | Desired in Output |
+ -------------- + --- + ----------------- +
| 1              | A   | Y                 |
| 1              | B   | Y                 |
| 2              | A   | Y                 |
| 2              | D   | Y                 |
| 3              | F   | N                 |
| 3              | G   | N                 |
+ -------------- + --- + ----------------- +
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

You could use a subquery

```
Select *
    From Test 
    Where Transaction_ID in (
        select Transaction_ID
            from Test
            where SKU = 'A'
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists()` in your `where` like so:

```
select *
from t
where exists (
  select 1
  from t as i
  where i.TransactionId = t.TransactionId
    and Sku = 'A'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an inner join to select Transaction id's that contain A:

```
create table #test
(
Transaction_id int,
Sku varchar(1)
)

insert into #test (Transaction_id, Sku) values (1, 'A')
insert into #test (Transaction_id, Sku) values (1, 'B')
insert into #test (Transaction_id, Sku) values (2, 'A')
insert into #test (Transaction_id, Sku) values (2, 'D')
insert into #test (Transaction_id, Sku) values (3, 'F')
insert into #test (Transaction_id, Sku) values (3, 'G')

select t.Transaction_id, t.Sku
from #test t
join 
(
    select Transaction_id
    from #test
    where Sku = 'A'

) x on x.Transaction_id = t.Transaction_id

drop table #test
```